# Finding binary ones in a number with Two's complement, C

Tags: c, binary

I think i might be making this a bit complicated.  We are supposed to pass in a long, and return the number of 1's in the binary representation of the number.  For negatives, we return two's complement.  I have the positives working, but two's complement is a bit off.  Any tips for making this work would be appreciated.

```
unsigned int binaryOnesCounter(long n) {


 unsigned int oneCounter, negCounter;
  int binaryStorage[63];
  int index, negFlag;

  oneCounter = negFlag = index = 0;


  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 63; ++i)
  {
    binaryStorage[i] = 0;
  }

  if(n < 0) {
    if (n == -1){
      oneCounter = 63 + 1;
    } else {
      /* negate and add 1*/
      negFlag = 1;
      n = (n * -1) + 1;
    }
  }
  while (n>=1) {
    if (n%2 == 1) {
      oneCounter++;
      binaryStorage[index] = 1;
    }
    else if (n%2 == 0) {
      binaryStorage[index] = 0;
    }
    n = n/2;
  }


  if (negFlag == 1 && n != 1) {
    negCounter = 64;
    oneCounter = negCounter - oneCounter;
  }
  return oneCounter;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Pass in a 64 bit integer and return the number of 1's in the binary representation. Two's complement for negatives.

Comment: You can convert the number to `uint64_t` and then use bitshifts and bitmasks instead.

Comment: There should be about 1000 questions on "how to count bits"...

Comment: Think about splitting your `int` into bytes and implement the hamming weight through a 256-bytes lookup table. should be the fastest method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is overcomplicated

```
int countones(long long i)
{
    int nOnes = 0;
    unsigned long long *ptr = &i;

    while (*ptr)
    {
        nOnes += *ptr & 1;
        *ptr >>= 1;
    }
    return nOnes;
}
```

PS -4 has 62 ones not 63 0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100

Here is a bit more universal one (counts almost in any object)

```
int getbit(void *obj, size_t bit);

size_t countBitsUniversal(void *obj, size_t osize)
{
    size_t nOnes = 0, tmp = osize;
    osize <<= 3;

    if (osize && osize > tmp)
    {
        do
        {
            nOnes += getbit(obj, --osize);

        } while (osize);
    }
    return nOnes;
}

int getbit(void *obj, size_t bit)
{
    uint8_t *p = obj;

    return !!(p[bit >> 3] & (1 << (bit & 7)));
}

__________
usage example


double x;
printf("%zu\n", countBitsUniversal(&x, sizeof(x)));

long long arr[100];
printf("%zu\n", countBitsUniversal(arr, sizeof(arr)));
```

Comment: Yea, the twos complement were a bit off, that's what I was trying to solve.  This looks much more eloquent.

Comment: `it gives less than half for most negatives` what do you mean? Gives exactly as many as it should.

Comment: Sorry, we have to use a regular long as the parameter - I solved my own issue here.  I added a new long long, set it equal to the long, then set the pointer to that.

Comment: @Avallauch This solution is universal though, just change the types and it will work just as fine. Or better yet, stop using C's mumbo-jumbo default types and use stdint.h instead.

Answer (score 1):

The classic solution:

```
int countBits(unsigned long long x)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (x)
    {
        count++;
        x = x & (x - 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Althought I declared the above as taking a parameter of `unsigned long long`, it can be modified to be signed or of any integer type: (`char`, `int`, or `long`).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use bit shift and bit mask operations and bring your `n` into the correct representation (i.e. just `n` for positive values, or the 2-complement for negative `n`s).

If you operate on a system that represents negative values already as 2 complements (and most common systems do so), then you just have to view `n` as an unsigned value, i.e. `unsigned long ul = n`. Then, `ul` will contain the 2-complements representation of a negative `n`.

If you operate on a system that represents negative values in another form (e.g. one-complement and a sign bit), you could make the two's complement on your own:

```
unsigned int binaryOnesCounter(long n) {

    unsigned long ul;

    if (n < 0) {
        ul = -n;
        ul = (~ul) + 1;
    }
    else {
        ul = -n;
    }

    int count=0;
    while(ul) {
        if (ul & 0x01)
            count++;

        ul >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) is actually represented.

Let's assume you have a function

```
int bits_set_in_unsigned_long(unsigned long value);
```

which returns the number of ones in binary representation of `value`.

We can supply nonnegative inputs directly to that function. For negative inputs, we calculate their two's complement (in an `unsigned long`), and return the number of ones in that, per the problem definition:

```
int bits_set_in_long(long value)
{
    if (value >= 0)
        return bits_set_in_unsigned_long( (unsigned long)value );
    else
        return bits_set_in_unsigned_long( ~(ULONG_MAX - (unsigned long)value + 1UL) + 1UL );
}
```

You need to `#include <limits.h>` for `ULONG_MAX`.

Above, the expression

```
~(ULONG_MAX - (unsigned long)value + 1UL) + 1UL
```

converts `value` (of type `long`) to its `unsigned long` two's complement. Let's look at exactly how this is accomplished.

For the two's complement representation, we first need the negated value of `value`, as an unsigned long. However, on many architectures, `-LONG_MIN == LONG_MIN`, because `LONG_MAX` is smaller in magnitude than `LONG_MIN`. However, because we know at this point that the value is negative, we can cast the value first, and then adjust for its negativeness.

`(unsigned long)value` casts `value` to `unsigned long` type. If the value is representable in both types, the value stays the same; otherwise, modulo arithmetic is used (ISO C11, 6.3.1.3). Because `value` is negative at this point, the cast value is `value` plus `ULONG_MAX + 1UL`.

Therefore, to get `-value`, we subtract the cast value from `ULONG_MAX + 1UL`. Because `ULONG_MAX` and `1` are constants, the compiler might wish to add them first together, and then complain that it overflows the type (which it does not, because `unsigned long` type uses modulo arithmetic, and we are quite happy with that). So, I put the subtraction in the middle, just to quieten a warning some C compilers might otherwise emit (because some C compilers might believe that such constructs are usually inadvertent errors, even though they are perfectly standard C code).

In other words, `(ULONG_MAX - (unsigned long)value + 1UL)` gives us the magnitude (or absolute value) of `value`, as an `unsigned long`, since `value` is negative at this point.

To convert that to two's complement format, we need to invert all its binary digits -- which the C `~` operator accomplishes -- and finally add one. Thus, we arrive at

```
~(ULONG_MAX - (unsigned long)value + 1UL) + 1UL
```

Now, there are other ways to express the exact same thing in C, but I chose this p don't know of any articular one for two simple reasons: First, it was the easiest to prove correct, and second, the compiler I use (GCC) treats it as a no-op on architectures with two's complement representation for negative integers (or at least x86 and x86-64, which are the ones I tested on GCC-5.4.0). In other words, there is no reason to try and "optimize" the expression, unless you actually have an architecture with non-two's-complement representation for negative integers; simply because the expression already simplifies to nothing on two's complement architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a student exercise ? In that case this answer is probably not what you want since it does not show that you understood the exercise, but it is most likely the most efficient way to do it:

Provided that:

- Portability is not required
- gcc is the compiler being used

you could use __builtin_popcount(), something like this (if an 'unsigned int' is 4 bytes on your system, and 'long' is 8 bytes):

```
    unsigned int binaryOnesCounter(long n) {
        unsigned int nrOfOnes = __builtin_popcount((unsigned int)(n & 0xffffffff));

        nrOfOnes += __builtin_popcount((unsigned int)(n >> 32));
        return nrOfOnes;
    }
```

On some architectures this is done in hardware and gcc will probably benefit from that.

Note that the code example above assumes that sizeof(unsigned int) is 4 and sizeof(long) is 8

More about gcc __builtins [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

Comment: I appreciate it, I'll look over the GCC builtins.  It is a student exercise, but I don't submit code that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that may be more efficient than shifting 32 times, is to use look-up tables. Example with nibble-wise look-up:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t count_ones (uint32_t data)
{
  static const uint8_t ONES [16] = {0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4};
  uint32_t count = 0;

  while(data)
  {
    count += ONES[data & 0xF];
    data >>= 4;
  }

  return count;
}

int main()
{
  uint32_t data = 0xAABBCCDD;

  printf("%"PRIu32, count_ones(data));
}
```

This can be expanded to byte-wise look-up with a 256 bytes large look-up and so on.

In case of signed numbers, simply use the same function but cast the signed number to unsigned.